# Wordpress header displays Firefox and IE

Tags: wordpress

I'am a beginner of this kind of work. So please be patience!

My Header is a bit messy in Firefox, IE and mobile safari. The logo displays huge and over the nav bar. I manage to fix it by adding overflow: hidden;.

Its a wordpress site.

But it still doesnt displays in the right way.

This is what ive done to fix it.

```
.logo-wrapper {
  line-height: 2.5ex;
  height: 90px; /* 2.5ex for each visible line */
  overflow: hidden;
  /*Option 1: display: inline */
  /*Option 2: overflow: auto; */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";    
  display: block;    
  height: 0;    
  overflow: hidden; 

.clearfix:after {clear: both;}
.clearfix {zoom: 1;}
```

What im I doing wrong?

Check out the site: http://bit.ly/1akopZL

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply adding the following to your CSS:

```
.logo img {
    max-height: 100%
}
```

I gave this a text and it should do the trick.

**Edit:** taken responsiveness into consideration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer flungo! I but in the code and actually the logo displays better with it. But it still displays different in firefox, do you see what i mean??

Comment: In Chrome it looks great, but still on the firefox, IE and the mobile safari, it looks like it float to the right and is resized.

Comment: Didn't notice that it was meant to be a responsive site. Having a look now.

Comment: Hi Flungo, thank you so much for helping me. Ive put in the code but it doesnt do the trick. It still look a bit messy when i enter the site with IE and Firefox.

Comment: Everything on the site looks good but the logo is displayed different.